# Using Jenkins triggers to execute a pipeline's test suite run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We use Jenkins 2.176 to manage our CI. In our `Jenkinsfile`, we've defined a trigger to start the pipeline M-F at 4:30AM, and we want it to skip testing in an ephemeral environment and deploying.

```
pipeline {
    triggers { cron('30 4 * * 1-5') }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            ...
        }
        stage('Tests') {
            ...
        }
        stage('Test in ephemeral environment') {
            when { triggeredBy 'SCMTrigger' }
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            when { allOf { branch 'master'; triggeredBy 'SCMTrigger' } }
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: the "Test in ephemeral environment" does not trigger when the branch is pushed via a git hook. The "Build" and "Tests" stages execute, but not the "Test in ephemeral environment". Once merged to master, I suspect I'll have a similar problem with the "Deploy" step but haven't made it that far.

What am I missing to make this work? It seems so straightforward

Comment: I have the slight impression that you have to configure an SCMTrigger, too. `pollSCM`

Comment: Good idea @SvenKrüger but I couldn't manage to get that working easily. Posted my solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to simply exclude `TimerTrigger` explicitly from steps I didn't want to execute. From my example, I did this:

```
pipeline {
    triggers { cron('30 4 * * 1-5') }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            ...
        }
        stage('Tests') {
            ...
        }
        stage('Test in ephemeral environment') {
            when { not { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' } }
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            when { allOf { branch 'master'; not { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' } } }
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```